# Formatting figure numbers to match with question number, including different figures within a question ie Fig. 2.1 and Fig 2.2

Tags: captions, enumerate

I am trying to write exam papers which include graphical elements. I have been able to make the figure reference match the question number but when there are two figures in a question I would like to reference each figure with the format eg 2.1 and 2.2. for figures in question 2.
I need this to be automatic to give me the option of moving questions for a best fit.
I feel that I probably need to use sections and subsections but have had no success.
In the simple code below you will see Q3 has two figures which are currently Fig.3 and Fig.4 - I would like them to be Fig.3.1 and Fig.3.2.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=12mm, top=12mm, right=12mm, bottom=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Question 1

\setcounter{figure}{\value{enumi}}%
\item Fig.\ref{A1} shows triangle \textit{ABC}.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.4]
            \draw [line width = 0.5mm] (0,0) coordinate(A) node[left]{A}--++(0:3) coordinate(B) node[right]{B}--++(64:4) coordinate(C) node[above]{C}--cycle;
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{} \label{A1} }
\end{figure}


\item Fig.\ref{A2} shows a sector of a circle of radius 8 cm.\\[2mm]
The angle of the sector is 2.1 radians.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering{         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
            \draw [line width = 0.5mm,fill=gray!30] (0,0) --  (220:4)  arc(220:120:4) -- cycle ;
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{} \label{A2} }
\end{figure}

Fig.\ref{A3} shows a sector of a circle of radius 8 cm.\\[2mm]
The angle of the sector is 2.1 radians.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering{         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
            \draw [line width = 0.5mm,fill=gray!30] (0,0) --  (220:4)  arc(220:120:4) -- cycle;         
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{} \label{A3} }
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{\value{enumi}}%
\item Another Question. Fig \ref{A4} 
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering{ \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
            \draw [line width = 0.5mm,fill=gray!30] (0,0) --  (220:4)  arc(220:120:4) -- cycle;         
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{} \label{A4} }
\end{figure}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you should really use `\section`s, and then simply `\numberwithin{figure}{section}`. Unrelated: I seriously doubt you are really using `latin1` encoding.

Comment: Do you every use figures outside questions?

Comment: I thought i had removed all unnecessary packages!!  In answer to your question John - No, not when I am writing exam papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also redefine `\thefigure` at will.  They are local to groups (environments), but `\item` is not a group.  You could create a question environment (like exam class) which calls `\item` for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=12mm, top=12mm, right=12mm, bottom=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\theenumi}% reverts after \end{enumerate}
\item Question 1
\item Fig.\ref{A1} shows triangle \textit{ABC}.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.4]
            \draw [line width = 0.5mm] (0,0) coordinate(A) node[left]{A}--++(0:3) coordinate(B) node[right]{B}--++(64:4) coordinate(C) node[above]{C}--cycle;
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{} \label{A1} }
\end{figure}


\item Fig.\ref{A2} shows a sector of a circle of radius 8 cm.\\[2mm]
The angle of the sector is 2.1 radians.
\begin{figure}[H]
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\theenumi.A}% reverts after figure
    \centering{         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
            \draw [line width = 0.5mm,fill=gray!30] (0,0) --  (220:4)  arc(220:120:4) -- cycle ;
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{} \label{A2} }
\end{figure}

Fig.\ref{A3} shows a sector of a circle of radius 8 cm.\\[2mm]
The angle of the sector is 2.1 radians.
\begin{figure}[H]
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\theenumi.B}% reverts after figure
    \centering{         \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
            \draw [line width = 0.5mm,fill=gray!30] (0,0) --  (220:4)  arc(220:120:4) -- cycle;         
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{} \label{A3} }
\end{figure}

\item Another Question. Fig \ref{A4} 
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering{ \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
            \draw [line width = 0.5mm,fill=gray!30] (0,0) --  (220:4)  arc(220:120:4) -- cycle;         
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{} \label{A4} }
\end{figure}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is great - works exactly as I wanted and much easier than I had anticipated.  I hadn't seen '\thefigure' and '\theenumi' as ways to reference then relevant numbers before.